# Django redirect for legazy php url

Tags: php, django, url-routing

Basically what I want to do is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^old/site/url.php?someshit=(?P<id>\d+)', 
    'website.views.redirect_php'),
)
```

But I always get a 404 ..

I've also tried to escape it like this

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^old/site/url\.php\?someshit\=(?P<id>\d+)', 
    'website.views.redirect_php'),
)
```

No luck.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing does not work because GET parameters are not included in the string being matched by URLconf. (See [What the URLconf searches against](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against).)

To achieve the desired behaviour, you'll need to extract the GET parameter from within the view and redirect according.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^old/site/url\.php$',
        view='website.views.redirect_php', 
        name='redirect_php'
    ),
)
```

and in your view:

```
def redirect_php(request):
    id = request.GET.get("somesheet", None)
    if id == None:
        # handle case where "somesheet=?" was not provided
    else:
        # handle redirects based on id
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^old/site/url\.php?someshit=(?P<id>\d+)$',
    'website.views.redirect_php', name='redirect_php'),
)
```

Comment: Doesn't work .. even if I replace (?P<id>\d+) with the actual id and type the id manually in the URL bar. It saiys it doesn't match any URLs..

Comment: Hmm. Let me see if I can find a solution for you.

Comment: Found the problem .. See the answer below. Thanks ;)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you couldn't match get parameters.